# Getting incomplete or partial access token of Azure DevOps with PowerShell script if executes from c#

Tags: c#, wpf, powershell, azure-active-directory, access-token

I am using PowerShell to access Azure DevOps Access Token because I don't have my PAT in string format. I am developing desktop-based applications with WPF and running the following PowerShell script from this WPF application. ***It executing successfully but giving me a partial or incomplete access token with a length of 1289 characters. And if I run the same script directly on PowerShell ISE then it gives the complete Access token of length 2126 characters.***

**PS Script for Access token**

```
param (
    [string]
    $applicationid,
    [string]
    $secretKey,
    [string]
    $tenantID,
    [string]
    $subscriptionId
)

Clear-AzureRmContext -Force;
$password = ConvertTo-SecureString -String $secretKey -AsPlainText -Force;
$cred = New-Object System.Management.Automation.PSCredential($applicationid,$password);
Connect-AzureRmAccount -ServicePrincipal -Credential $cred -Tenant $tenantID;

Select-AzureRmSubscription -SubscriptionId $subscriptionId
$currentAzureContext = Get-AzureRmContext;
$azureRmProfile = [Microsoft.Azure.Commands.Common.Authentication.Abstractions.AzureRmProfileProvider]::Instance.Profile;
$profileClient = New-Object Microsoft.Azure.Commands.ResourceManager.Common.RMProfileClient($azureRmProfile);
$pat = $profileClient.AcquireAccessToken($currentAzureContext.Subscription.TenantId).AccessToken;
Write-Output $pat
```

**C# Code is below**

```
 var fileName = Path.Combine(Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData), "myAppFolder", "Script.ps1");
 string scriptpath = fileName + " -applicationid " + thisApp.xmlSettings.ClientId + " -secretKey " + thisApp.xmlSettings.ClientKey + " -tenantID " + thisApp.xmlSettings.TenantId + " -subscriptionId " + thisApp.xmlSettings.SubscriptionId + "";
 PowerShell psExec = PowerShell.Create();
 psExec.AddScript(scriptpath);
 psExec.AddCommand("out-string");
 StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
 Collection<PSObject> results;
 Collection<ErrorRecord> errors;
 results = psExec.Invoke();
 errors = psExec.Streams.Error.ReadAll();

 if (errors.Count > 0)
 {
      foreach (ErrorRecord error in errors)
      {
           sb.AppendLine(error.ToString());
      }
 }
 else
 {
     foreach (PSObject result in results)
     {
         string[] token = result.BaseObject.ToString().Split(new char[] { '\n' });
         thisApp.staticAccessToken = token[14].ToString();
     }
}
```

Please correct me where I am doing wrong. I am able to consume REST APIs of Azure DevOps if I have an access token of length 2126 characters and I get 404 if my access token's length is 1289.

Comment: Instead of adding `Out-String` to the pipeline, you should just consume the last object returned and cast to `string`: `thisApp.staticAccessToken = (string)results[results.Count - 1].BaseObject;`

Comment: Hi Mathians R. Jessen, I tried your suggestion and i am getting 1279 length access token.

Comment: And you removed `psExec.AddCommand("out-string");`? Strange. If you take a look at the string value, does it look like an access token?

Comment: yes I had removed the psExec.AddCommand("out-string") yes it looks like access token but length was short.